# How to reset inbuilt events to null so that a View can be disposed

Tags: c#, wpf

The problem is that in my View I am subscribing to a CollectionChanged  event like so:

InitializeComponent();
CollectionChanged += SomeMethod

Whenever DataTemplate redraws the View it will always chain SomeMethod to CollectionChanged. 
And I think that because of the reference the old View does not get GC'd. I suspect it may be the cause of the leak I am having.
I need to register SomeMethod to CollectionChanged, so the question is.. how can I clear CollectionChanged. Do UserControl have a way method to clear all subscriptions to events? 
Thanks.

Comment: CollectionChanged -= SomeMethod?

Comment: I know but where would I put that? In the constructor as well?
So you are saying

 `CollectionChanged -= SomeMethod;`
 `CollectionChanged += SomeMethod;`

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that you have something along the lines of:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        collection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(collection_CollectionChanged);
    }
```

And assuming that collection lives longer than this Form, then the above event handler will prevent the form from being garbage collected. Assuming you are creating a new form every time you display it, you can unsubscribe in the form's FormClosed event, along the lines of:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        collection.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(collection_CollectionChanged);
        FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosed);
    }

    void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        collection.CollectionChanged -= new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(collection_CollectionChanged);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah thanks. Before I saw this post I used the Unload event. Would  that work as well?

Comment: Sorry I thought you were doing WinForms not WPF. For WPF, yes the Unload event.